# невозможно выполнить npm install (npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601, npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE)

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Изначально разработка велась на Windows 10 с версией node.js 18.18.0 и npm 9.8.1. Далее, разработку пришлось продолжать в системе Windows server 2008 r2 c установленными node.js 4.9.0 и npm 2.5.1. И вот на этом этапе возникла проблема с установкой пакетов node.js. При запуске npm install возникает ошибка с их установкой. Распространенный вариант решения не помог, т.е. удаление package.lock, node_modules и последующая попытка выполнить npm install.

package.json:

[image: package.json]

ошибка:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\MI\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\MI\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! esbuild@0.18.20 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the esbuild@0.18.20 postinstall script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the esbuild package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs esbuild
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls esbuild
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\MI\OSPanel\domains\device-manager\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Приложите текст ошибки текстом. На скрине вообще ничего не видно.

Comment: Vite [требует Node.js 14.18+, 16+](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project), все остальные зависимости скорее всего так же требуют более поздних версий, чем Ваша.

Comment: @Simon спасибо, это проясняет проблему